# How to track a users activity on a server with discord py?

Tags: python, discord.py

So to put it simply: I want to create a command for a discord bot coded in discord py with which I can track a users activity on a server. Preferably it should output when a specified user last sent a message and when they last joined any voice chat. The output doesnt have to be a visually pleasing box, a standard text message is just fine

I plan to use this command to convert it to a function that the bot automatically bans a user if hasnt had activity on the server within the past year. I sorta want to figure this one out on my own. But if it isnt possible, please tell me.

My knowledge with the discord.py API is still pretty limited and I find the documentation to be quite a mess and couldnt find anything relating to this.

Am I missing something or is it just not possible with discord.py due to various reasons? Would it be possible with discord.js if it isnt in discord.py?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible with discord.py

*Reminder: people on this site will complain about the fact that you did not provided a code, and this site is for error handling.*

Anyways here is the code for users last message:

```
@bot.command()
async def first_message(ctx:commands.Context, user: discord.User):
    channel = ctx.channel
    
    first_message = None
    
    async for message in channel.history(limit=None):
        if message.author == user:
            first_message = message
            break

    if first_message:
        formatted_time = first_message.created_at.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
        await ctx.send(f"{user.mention} first sent a message at {formatted_time}")
    else:
        await ctx.send(f"{user.mention} hasn't sent any messages in this channel.")
```

However I recommand you use this as a Slash command, because like this if you want to check your own last message it will return the time when you executed the command.